# How to justify text in a textbox ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitextfield, storyboard

I am developing an app for the iphone. One of my views contains a textbox that I used to display text. I used storyboard to do this. To better explain, this view will show the user  the history of a football team. E.g " the team was established in 1990" etc and give a full history of the team.  So there will be no user interaction. The reader will only read the text and move on to the next page. Is using a textbox for the text a good idea? And is there anyway to justify the alignment of the text so the ends of the lines are all alligned?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think You will Use WebView Because justified aligment for text you only have center, left and right by UItextView.

IF You Want to Use UiWebView then set in

```
className.h

@interface className : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIWebView *webviewName;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *webviewName;
```

className.m

```
[webviewName loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div align='justify'>%@<div>",TEXT_set] baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

[`UITextView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) is a good way to go, but it has no option to justify the text it contains. Another approach is using a [`UIWebView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/) to display a simple HTML document.

To have nice looking justified text in HTML set the `text-align` property to `justify` and may use some JavaScript to [enhance line-breaking](http://www.bramstein.com/projects/typeset/).

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

ok there is no problem with that u shoud to use textView ,just make sure its user intteraction is disable, while if ur data is coming dynamic than u should to use Web view, this make alignment correct

Answer (score 0):

I have found that a generic view controller subclass to load a web view is very reusable. I have two. One designed for a navigation controller, and another designed a a modal view controller. I use them over and again with modification for things like help, legal information, and about my company. It would work very well for your purposes.

I use KempoZer as my free html editor to create the files I load in it. The advantage is that the html editor allows me to add bold, italic, headings, and different font sizes.

In storyboard I have several segues to the same view controller and set the two properties in a prepare for segue method in the view controller that calls the html view controller.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"instructions"])  {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setNavigationTitle:@"Instructions"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setHtmlFileName:@""];        
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"legal"])  {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setNavigationTitle:@"Legal Notices"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setHtmlFileName:@"legal.html"];        
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"about"])  {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setNavigationTitle:@"About"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setHtmlFileName:@"AboutSuperDuperCoolApps.html"];        
    } else if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"videoTutorials"])  {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setNavigationTitle:@"Video Tutorials"];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setHtmlFileName:@""];        
    }
}
```

Here is the nab controller version, don't forget to create the storyboard view controller and hook up the web view.

```
//  HTMLViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface HTMLViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *htmlFileName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *navigationTitle;

@end
```

and

```
//  HTMLViewController.

#import "HTMLViewController.h"

@implementation HTMLViewController
@synthesize webView, htmlFileName, navigationTitle;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:navigationTitle];
    // load selected html file
    NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *webPath = [bundle stringByAppendingPathComponent:htmlFileName];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                          [NSURL fileURLWithPath:webPath]]];
    //
    [super viewDidLoad];

}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setWebView:nil];
    [self setHtmlFileName:nil];
    [self setNavigationTitle:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```